# Multiple videos on screen using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

What I want to achieve here is a screen with 2 or more different videos on at a time. I know in the apple documentation it says you can't have more than one video playing at a time and thats fine, I don't want to do this.

All I want is to have the 2 videos on screen and when you press on it, it starts to play, you can go fullscreen if you want but as soon as you press on a different video, the old video stops and the new one starts.

I already have three MPMoviePlayerController set up with the correct position, size and video and the 3 boxes are all drawn to the screen but at the moment, only the last one to be drawn to screen can actually be watched.

Does anybody know if there is any way to achieve this or not and if so, how would I go about it?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3):

As for as I know, you can only have one active movie player at the same time. It's a limitation from MPMoviePlayerController. Message in Apple documentation :

> Note: Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects
>   and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a
>   time can play its movie.

Source : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: In fact, if you try more than one - it is just completely broken.  they all just come up black.  (You can't "play one at once" - they all simply don't work.)